# Error initializing filter 'mandelbrot' with args 's=7680x4320:r=60', Cannot allocate memory

Tags: linux, memory, ffmpeg

When I attempt to execute the following:

ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=7680x4320:r=60 -vf "[in]drawtext=DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf: text='mandelbrot-libvpx-vp9-7680x4320x60p': fontcolor=white: fontsize=72: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5: x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-100, drawtext=DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf:text='-0-yuv420p-75.webm': fontcolor=white: fontsize=72: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5: boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-25[out]" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -profile:v 0 -b:v 75M -minrate 75M -maxrate 75M -bufsize 150M -pix_fmt yuv420p -framerate 60 -t 10 -y mandelbrot-libvpx-vp9-7680x4320x60p-0-yuv420p-75.webm

I see

> ffmpeg version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
> built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
> configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1 --enable-shared
> --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox   libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100   libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100   libavformat
> 59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100   libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100   libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100   libswscale      6.  7.100 /
> 6.  7.100   libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100   libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100 [lavfi @ 0x7fb33dd11f00] Error initializing filter 'mandelbrot' with args 's=7680x4320:r=60'
> mandelbrot=s=7680x4320:r=60: Cannot allocate memory

I found in this source: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/vsrc__mandelbrot_8c_source.html, that "s->cache_allocated = s->w * s->h * 3;"  Perhaps, that means 100MB is needed per image?

Is this an issue with ffmpeg, or this particular filter or do I need more memory than the 16GB my Mac provides?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think the issue is in the next line of code: `s->point_cache= av_malloc_array(s->cache_allocated, sizeof(*s->point_cache))`. Size of [Point](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structPoint.html) is at least 22 bytes. `s->point_cache = `7680*4320*3*22` = `2189721600`. The size is grater than MAX_INT (`2147483647`). It looks like `av_malloc_array` is limited to MAX_INT size (I don't know if the limitation is a bug). In case you want to fix the sources... replace `av_malloc_array` with `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed line 72 of https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavutil/mem.c from "static atomic_size_t max_alloc_size = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(INT_MAX);" to "static atomic_size_t max_alloc_size = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(2*INT_MAX);"  With that I was able to generate the 8k assets I need.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a command line option named `max_alloc` to change the value of `max_alloc_size` so no re-compilation is required e.g.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=7680x4320:r=60 -t 2 -max_alloc 8589934592 test.ts
```